# Autosys job which checks other job status

Tags: autosys

I'm looking for a temporary solution for my autosys flow:

**JobA** - job which doing something and its running for around 30 minutes (25-35 min)

**JobA** is quite critical for batch dependency. I have max run alarm on it. But sometimes it is running too long (1h+). Of course it is something which has to be fixed but due to various of reasons it cannot be done right now.

What I'm looking for now sounds like some sort if dirty hack but it totally helped me
I would like to create job called: **jobA_check** which will start together with **JobA**.

**JobA_check** - command which in loop checks status of JobA

- when **JobA** is running more than 30 minutes - **JobA_check** fails
- when **JobA** finished <30 min JobA_check goes to SU

Is it doable?

Comment: what is the trigger for JobA - is it time based or file based ?

Answer (score 0):

If Job A is time-based.

```
insert_job: JobA_Check
job_type: CMD 
machine: localhost
command: bash /absolute_path/Notification_script_name.sh
start_times: "00:30"     /* +30 mins of start of jobA */
condition: R(JobA)
days_of_week: all
timezone: US/Eastern
```

Check for ways to connect to Autosys instance via CLI, general process is install the Autosys ixp cli package, export the instance variables and then you can issue autorep command straight from the host.